# Bound Google Apps Script project deployed as web app stopped working

Tags: deployment

I had an old apps script project deployed for years that has stopped working as of Feb. 3. I have no idea why and I never got any notification about needing to do something to fix it.

Now when I try to execute the head version, it says Not Found.

What is the issue here and how do I fix it?

Thanks,
Jayaram

Script ID: 12_ImeOVnKUroR86SyzelAqT4RhaVoyK1Jig2m1u6dQSFK9YwQjD9EZ4w

Web app URL: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzg-E-ePbvta2S8yZ7y6nvoyMrwX2OimUsxBNObjZ1YNWCIuYE/exec

[image: execution error]

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Hi, please share more information, like URL, src, etc.. so we can investigate further.

Comment: I have updated the post. Thanks.